# Some Assistance On Reply To Comments PHP

Tags: php, smarty

Could someone give me some assistance on adding reply to my commenting system.

I'm creating a project on Smarty 3 and so far i have done the comments part but i'm having a bit of trouble with the reply part because it won't display the replies could someone check my code to see what i am doing wrong or correct it for me please here is my code below.

PHP Functions from movie class

```
public function GetMovieComments($con, $movie_id) {
    $c = array();
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `movie_comments`,`user` WHERE `movie_id` = '".$movie_id."' AND `uid` = `user_id`");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $c[] = $r;
        }
        return $c;
    }   
}

public function GetMovieReplies($con, $comment_id) {
    $comment_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $comment_id);
    $rp = array();
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `movie_replies`,`user` WHERE `comment_id` = '".$comment_id."' AND `uid` = `user_id`");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $rp[] = $r;
        }
        return $rp;
    }   
}
```

Now calling the functions from movie.php

```
$comments = $movie->GetMovieComments($con, $movie_id);

if (isset($comments)) {
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        $comment_id = $comment['cid'];
        $replies = $movie->GetMovieReplies($con, $comment_id);
        $smarty->assign('replies',$replies);
    }
}

$smarty->assign('comments', $comments);
```

Now in movie.tpl

```
{if isset($comments)}
    {if $comments neq ''}
        {foreach from=$comments key=key item=comment}
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-body">{$comment.comment}</div>
            </div>
            {foreach from=$replies key=key item=reply}
                <h4>{$reply.reply}</h4>
            {/foreach}
        {/foreach}
    {else}
        <h5>No Comments</h5>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

Could someone please help me i have been trying to solve this for hours lol thanks

Comment: I think in this line you might be overwriting what you put there previously: `$smarty->assign('replies',$replies);`. However I don't have experience with smarty so just a guess...

Comment: i don't think that is the issue because when i assigned `replies` to `$replies` that's only for the template uses and i did the same with the `comments` part and it did not affect that :(.

Comment: Yes, but realize that you are assigning `comments` only once, at the end of your script. However, `replies` is being assigned in every loop that the `foreach()` does.

Comment: oh yeah sorry i'll see what happens when i move it out of the loop.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot really just take it out... you'll need to figure something else

Comment: Ok so say now your in my shoes what would you do to add replies to my comments system?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For not overwriting the variable replies, I'd do something like this:

```
// Make GetMovieComments return an array with values or simply an array(), so no check needed
$comments = $movie->GetMovieComments($con, $movie_id);

foreach($comments as $key => $comment) {
  $replies = $movie->GetMovieReplies($comment['cid']);
  $comments[$key]['replies'] = $replies;
  }

$smarty->assign('comments', $comments);
```

Then you can access the `{foreach from=$comment.replies key=key item=reply}` to use it within the inner foreach. However that was just one thing, there might be more mistakes in the code...

A couple of things I'd do extra with your code:

```
public function GetMovieComments($movie_id) {
    $comments = array();
    // Some data validation to avoid SQL Injections
    // You might be better with binding parameters if it's not an int
    $id = intval($movie_id);
    // You use the connection already stored in this object. You should set it in the constructor
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM `movie_comments`,`user` WHERE `movie_id` = '" . $id . "' AND `uid` = `user_id`");
    // No need for the if. This will only enter if there's any result anyway
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $comments[] = $result;
        }
    return $comments;
    }

// Apply some similar changes to GetMovieReplies() as the ones above.
```

Comment: might be more mistakes? have you spotted another issue with my code lol :)

Comment: I thought that wasn't it, since it was the first thing I saw. I'd make a couple of changes more in your code, as seen in my edit. However not that you'd also need to change the `__constructor()` of `$movie` to store the `$conn` if you like my suggestions. Variables like `$c`, `$p` etc might seem okay now, but it adds some extra overhead to you when you try to understand the code later on, so I'd suggest avoiding them aswell.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help :) and i will keep in mind about using short named variables thank you.